# pg-promise returns decimal as string values

Tags: node.js, pg-promise, node-postgres

[pg-promise](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/index.html) returns the decimal values as string. How do I fix this?

```
select round(avg(numcol),2)::decimal from details
```

Comment: The same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42901913/decimal-value-in-postgresql-returned-as-string-in-node-js), and solution is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39168501/pg-promise-returns-integers-as-strings).

Comment: @vitaly-t Thanks for sharing the solution. But the thing is I am new to pg-promise. A complete example would be helpful.

Comment: Isn't it what I gave you in my answer? What else are you expecting?

Comment: I am not sure where to use the code you provided in the answer. So I just used javascript parseFloat in db.each(query, values, data=>{...}). It worked.

Comment: You should learn the basics of using the library first, it is all very clear there. This wouldn't be the right place for discussing how to use the library.

Answer (score -1):

Following the links I provided in the comments ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42901913/decimal-value-in-postgresql-returned-as-string-in-node-js) and [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39168501/pg-promise-returns-integers-as-strings)), you should see that JavaScript simply doesn't have the required precision, so automatic conversion may result in lost precision.

If you do not care about that, you can apply JavaScript standard `parseFloat`:

```js
const types = pgp.pg.types; // types conversion interface

// for real/float4:
types.setTypeParser(700, parseFloat);

// for double precision/float8:
types.setTypeParser(701, parseFloat);

// for arrays of float4:
const parseFloat4Array = types.getTypeParser(1021);
types.setTypeParser(1021, a => parseFloat4Array(a).map(parseFloat));

// for arrays of float8:
const parseFloat8Array = types.getTypeParser(1022);
types.setTypeParser(1022, a => parseFloat8Array(a).map(parseFloat));
```

Otherwise, use a specialized library for dealing with decimals.