# TypeORM - Decimal column values returned as strings instead of decimal / numbers

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

I dont know why, but but column values always get returned as strings instead of decimals and I dont know how to fix this issue.

They get stored properly in the database, but when I query using QueryBuilder, the results are shown as strings.

```js
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity({name:"collectionstats"})
export class CollectionStats {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;
  @Column("decimal")
  one_day_volume: number;
  @Column("decimal")
  one_day_change: number;
  @Column("decimal")
  one_day_sales: number;
  @Column("decimal")
  one_day_average_price: number;
  @Column("decimal")
  seven_day_volume: number;
  @Column("decimal")
  seven_day_change: number;
  @Column("decimal")
  seven_day_sales: number;
  @Column("decimal")
  seven_day_average_price: number;
  @Column("decimal")
  thirty_day_volume: number;
  @Column("decimal")
  thirty_day_change: number;
  @Column("decimal")
  thirty_day_sales: number;
  @Column("decimal")
  thirty_day_average_price: number;
  @Column("decimal")
  total_volume: number;
  @Column("decimal")
  total_sales: number;
  @Column("decimal")
  total_supply: number;
  @Column("decimal")
  count: number;
  @Column("decimal")
  num_owners: number;
  @Column("decimal")
  average_price: number;
  @Column("decimal")
  num_reports: number;
  @Column("decimal")
  market_cap: number;
  @Column("decimal")
  floor_price: number;
}
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42902057/9018946) answer your question?

Answer (score 31):

Here is a [solution from the TypeORM issue tracker](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/873#issuecomment-424643086):

> Sharing a transformer we use:
>
> ```
> /// ColumnNumericTransformer
> export class ColumnNumericTransformer {
>   to(data: number): number {
>     return data;
>   }
>   from(data: string): number {
>     return parseFloat(data);
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> In entity:
>
> ```
>  @Column('numeric', {
>     precision: 7,
>     scale: 2,
>     transformer: new ColumnNumericTransformer(),
>   })
>   public myNumericColumn: number;
> ```

Comment: I've now added the code for you. In the future, please follow this pattern when linking to external resources.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the answer of  Jefferson didnt work.

I was using a TypeOrm Query Builder and did this:

`.select('myNumericColumn :: float')`