# Decimal type transformed to string in NestJS/Prisma/Graphql

Tags: javascript, graphql, nestjs, apollo, prisma

I have a field of type `Decimal`, but when I fetch the data from the client, I receive my field as a `string` which is supposed to be of type `number`

My Object Type:

```
import { Decimal } from '@prisma/client/runtime/library';
import { GraphQLDecimal } from 'prisma-graphql-type-decimal';

@ObjectType()
export class Supplier {
    @Field(() => GraphQLDecimal, {nullable:false})
    commission!: Decimal;
}
```

The response :

```
{
    // Other fields....
    id: 7;
    isConfirmed: false;
    webAppLanguage: 'fr';

    // Should be number
    commission: '0.3';
}
```

---

**What I've tried :**

I tried adding field-based middleware with nestjs to transform decimal objects into number types, but it didn't work.

```
export const decimalCastMiddleWare: FieldMiddleware = async (
    ctx: MiddlewareContext,
    next: NextFn,
) => {
    let value = await next();

    if (Decimal.isDecimal(value)) {
        value = value.toNumber();
    }

    return value;
};

// Middleware field-based
{
    buildSchemaOptions: {
        // Other ApolloDriverConfig config options...
        fieldMiddleware: [decimalCastMiddleWare]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70127622/12599279), try it

```
Sharing a transformer we use:

/// ColumnNumericTransformer
export class ColumnNumericTransformer {
  to(data: number): number {
    return data;
  }
  from(data: string): number {
    return parseFloat(data);
  }
}
in entity:

 @Column('numeric', {
    precision: 7,
    scale: 2,
    transformer: new ColumnNumericTransformer(),
  })
  public myNumericColumn: number;
```